# .htaccess redirect query strings

Tags: regex, .htaccess

This was kind of hard to search for, I found examples of other work but basically I have a url:

```
site.com/?page=test&id=3
```

I want to rewrite as: `site.com/test:3`

with 'test' being page, and 3 being id.

I have the following match for equal values:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(\w+)=(\w+)$
RewriteRule ^/ /%1:%2?
```

But that only works for the key and the value, what regex can I use to select just the key, with %1 and %2 ?

Thanks,

My Second Attempt:
(I only need on index.php)

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=(\w+)&id=([0-9]*)$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /%1:%2**?** [R=302,L]
```

but now a 404 error is occuring when I do: index.php/details:1

Comment: Whats inside the brackets ends up in your variables. Try `^\w+=(\w+)$`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?test=([^\s&]+)&test2=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /%1:%2? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^([^:]+):([^/]+)/?$ /?test=$1&test2=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: sweet, but what if the queries are not present? I get 404.

Comment: For which URL you get 404?

Comment: If I went to the index of a directory. ie: site.com/

Comment: Then this rule won't even fire since none of the conditions will meet that URI `/`. Do you have other rules?

Comment: No other rules, and everything is on the index.php file. I only need it for that file. index.php?test=name&test2=integer (with other variations of name & integer)

Comment: Try placing `DirectoryIndex index.php` line on top. Other than that I don't see any problem with these rules. If you rename these 2 rules does 404 go away?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57346/discussion-between-anubhava-and-mysterydev).

Comment: Did you try: `DirectoryIndex index.php` ? And I sent you a chat link